# Google sign in - "Blank Page" - one moment please

Tags: google-authentication, google-signin

I'm seeing this page between the google sign page and my app page. Every time after I input my password to login my app using google account I will see this blank page with a sentence - one moment please.. However, this page will disappear after a half second.

I checked other apps where you can login using google account and it seems like some of them also have this kind issue.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? It seems like a problem from the google side not my app.

[image]

Comment: I got similar issue. upon inspect console I also got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at failure (<anonymous>:41:30)
    at cb=gapi.loaded_0:359
    at e.vo (cb=gapi.loaded_0:239)
    at $k (cb=gapi.loaded_0:242)
    at Vk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:242)
    at _.Gk.oU (cb=gapi.loaded_0:242)
    at Fk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:234)`

Comment: Hi @Harry Xiong, Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @ousecTic This issue seems gone... i think it's google plugins problem and somehow they resolved the issue recently

Answer (score 1):

When encountering this on desktop, clear browser's cookies and retry from another IP address.

Comment: Clearing cookies worked for me — to do this on Chrome, an easy way is to open devtools, go to the "Application" tab, then open the "Cookies" dropdown, right click on `https://accounts.google.com` and select "Clear"